# [Protracot][IE11]-->When I click a link, it cannot open a new tab even I setup the IE browser correctly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Eg: ele.click();
It can open a new tab in Chrome/FF, but not IE11.

And also I manually click that link, it can open a new tab on IE11.

Can anyone tell me why? what should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: I find that the behavior on IE browser which launched by Protractor is different by IE browser I manually launched. The first one always pop up a new window, and the second one works well. Is this a IEdriver issue?

Answer (score 0):

With IE it's always a special case. *Click the link through javascript*:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele.getWebElement());
```